# path of regex_byref_matcher.hpp when using xp::sregex::compile

Tags: boost, compilation, boost-xpressive

I noticed that when I use xp::sregex::compile in my code, the string ...\3rdparty\boost-1_58\boost/xpressive/detail/core/matcher/regex_byref_matcher.hpp (with my local path) appears in the binary code, compiled in release mods.
Is there a way to remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is undoubtedly when the code  uses `__FILE__` to get nice assert/exception messages.

The only place where Xpressive uses it directly is in `regex_error.hpp`:

```
#define BOOST_XPR_ENSURE_(pred, code, msg)                                                          \
    boost::xpressive::detail::ensure_(!!(pred), code, msg, BOOST_CURRENT_FUNCTION, __FILE__, __LINE__)  \
    /**/
```

You could easily hack it to be

```
#include <boost/xpressive/regex_error.hpp>

#undef BOOST_XPR_ENSURE_

#define BOOST_XPR_ENSURE_(pred, code, msg)                                                          \
    boost::xpressive::detail::ensure_(!!(pred), code, msg, BOOST_CURRENT_FUNCTION, "(source-hidden)", __LINE__)  \
    /**/
```

Keep in mind:

- the hack needs to go *before any other* Xpressive includes
- this will limit the usefulness of the messages, should they occur
- there is a possibility that one of the libraries that Xpressive depends on uses similar constructs

Comment: please post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)/[MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense, I tried it but I still get the path of regex_byref_matcher.hpp in the binary, and I don't see the string "source-hidden"  instead.  Also it compiled successfully with only the undef so it didnt really meet this macro.